# Argument #1 ($connection) must be of type Doctrine\MongoDb\Connection, Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration given

Tags: mongodb

In `doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.x` i can get a `Connection` object like thus:-

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('DocumentManager')->getConnection();
```

```
object(Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection)#38 (6) {
  ["mongoClient":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["server":protected]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["options":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ssl"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ...
```

In `doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.x` this has been removed. How can I get the equivalent in `2.x` ?

I'm trying:-

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('DocumentManager')->getConfiguration();
$db = Zend_Registry::get('DocumentManager')->getClient();
$db = Zend_Registry::get('DocumentManager')->getDocumentDatabase('Model\User');
```

but none of these are the correct objects and I don't see anything similar to `Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection` in the `mongodb-odm` packages dir for `2.x`.

Comment: If you need the url, it's `(string)$dm->getClient()`

Comment: Thanks Alex. Sadly, my method signature depends on an object `must be of type Doctrine\MongoDb\Connection`

Comment: Oh, I believe you will need to refactor more than that. Many things have changed in odm v2. This is why it's a major version increment - there are breaking changes there.